# QUnit: Any official solution to not output results within websites DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I had a quick look at [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/), a framework for unit testing JavaScript. My intention was to debug complex website behavior with QUnit.

However, per default it seems that all output of QUnit is generated within the DOM tree. Therefore, any JavaScript in test which works on the DOM tree is potentially behaving differently when run a unit test. I mean, the real website won't have the output sections of QUnit.

I found some way to output the results into the browser's console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <!-- not needed      <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit-1.15.0.css"> -->
  <style>
      #test {
          background-color: #ff9900;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- not needed...

  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
-->

  <script src="qunit-1.15.0.js"></script>
  <script src="tests.js"></script>

  <div id="testdiv">My normal DOM DATA</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Within my tests.js I have the following snippet:

```
QUnit.log(function( details ) {
  console.log( "QUnit: '" + details.name + "' = "
      + (details.result ? "PASS" : "FAIL,  " + "'"+details.message+"'"));
});
```

This works. However, my current open issues with that quick&dirty solution are:

1. I need to open the console of my browser. An existing solution could possibly generate an `alert()` when all tests are done (summing up all results). Adapting the above code for sending an `alert()` for a single failed/passed test is trivial (but see issue 3).
2. I can't enable the "noglobals" check feature, which I found to be quite handy. / Meaning, I couldn't find out how to set it via the JavaScript API.
3. I wonder if there is any existing / official solution (so I do not have to reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first off, yay for unit testing JavaScript! This is something often avoided for many of the reasons you highlight, so it's nice to see you're making an effort.

QUnit runs in a browser, it has to. There are other JS testing libraries which don't *absolutely have to* (Mocha, for example), but not really when testing web site code (mostly it's for testing Node). If you want to test your web site JS code, you need to be in a browser context. But more to your point, **no, you do not need to view the QUnit results in the browser.**

The easiest way to see the output is most likely to use an automation tool, although this is not the quickest thing to set up. For example, you could use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and the [QUnit plugin for Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit), which uses PhantomJS as the browser, to automate the test running and see the output in the terminal (not the browser JS console, but the Linux/Mac/Windows terminal). Grunt can also be used in Continuous Integration Tools like Jenkins, Travis, or TeamCity.

In fact, QUnit gives you the ability to get all results after a test run and do whatever you want with them. So you could write your own code to handle the results and do something with them (like send to an ajax endpoint for reporting):

```
var log = [];
// set up a handler to capture the output from QUnit.log()
// then put that output into the array above for reporting later
QUnit.testStart(function(testDetails){
  QUnit.log(function(details){
    if (!details.result) {
      details.name = testDetails.name;
      log.push(details);
    }
  });
});

// set up a callback for when the entire test suite is complete
QUnit.done(function (totals) {
  // do whatever you need to in here with the totals (http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.done/)
  // and with the individual test `log` array
});
```

So, to specifically answer your questions:

1. You could hook in a `window.alert(...)` to the `QUnit.done()` callback... but I think you'd be better off with an automation solution.
2. Although you can't programmatically set the `noglobals` switch through the API, you can simply tack it onto the URL for the test file: `http://localhost:1234/tests/index.html?noglobals=true`
3. See my examples above, we use Grunt in all our projects, but for cross browser testing I would look at [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/javascript/qunit) and their VM API.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. An automation solution is surely good for complex computations and analysis of AJAX-communication. Will have a detailed look at PhantomJS, too. This seems quite handy for all automated tests that aren't related to a special browser and/or displayed information on the screen (most probably those need to be checked manually or by comparing screenshots). If sauce labs is well, possibly nice for testing. But, their non-free options are unfortunately not an option for my non-commercial website projects.

Comment: PS: My projects are closed-source, as I don't other people using my afford for commercial purposes and gaining money out of it. So their free option for open-source projects aren't available to me...